# Assigning to column slices with df.loc and astype() *sometimes* issues SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, ipython

The code issuing the `SettingWithCopyWarning` can be fully replicated. See the edit below for more strange behaviour wrt consistency of getting the warning. FYI, this is **not a duplicate** of these 3 questions:

1. [python astype(str) gives SettingWithCopyWarning and requests I use loc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037970/1431750)

   - *"At some point prior to the assignment, you created df in such a way that it became a view into another dataframe."*
   - Mine can be created from scratch with the code below, and not from another df.
2. [Python - Getting “SettingWithCopyWarning” despite using df.loc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650685/1431750)

   - *"Create the 2nd dataframe with the following code..."*
   - I'm only creating and using one DataFrame.
3. [**How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/1431750)

   - I am using `.loc` but I'm assigning to a column slice; isn't covered in the answers there.

**The code:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'watermelon'],
    'Volume 1': [10, 20, 30, 700, 800],
    'Volume 2': [100, 200, 300, 7000, 8000],
    'Volume 3': [1, 2, 3, 70, 8],
    'Volume 4': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
    'Other': [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
})

df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'] = df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'].shift(1)
df = df.dropna()
# All okay so far, no warnings


# This next line issues a `SettingWithCopyWarning`:
df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'] = df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'].astype(int)  # warning
# and if I execute this line again, it now issues SWC warning:
df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'] = df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'].shift(1)  # warning

# And any following operation now issues the SWCW:
df['A'] = 'foo'  # new column
df['Fruits'] = 'a fruit'  # existing column
```

I can get rid of the warning by doing *either* one of:

```py
df = df.dropna()
# or
df = df.copy()
```

If I then redo different versions of the previous `astype()` step, **there's no warning**:

```py
df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'] = df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'].astype(float)  # no warning
df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'] = df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'].astype(int)  # no warning
```

If the first `astype()` step issues `SettingWithCopyWarning`, why didn't these? Shouldn't it be consistent? I'm on pandas version '1.2.2'.

Btw, even if I could explicitly list all the columns I was converting in *the first `astype()` step*, in these different ways, they also issue SWC warnings:

```py
df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'] = df[['Volume 2', 'Volume 3', 'Volume 4']].astype(int)
df[['Volume 2', 'Volume 3', 'Volume 4']] = df.loc[:, 'Volume 2':'Volume 4'].astype(int)
df[['Volume 2', 'Volume 3', 'Volume 4']] = df[['Volume 2', 'Volume 3', 'Volume 4']].astype(int)
```

*Edit/Update:* In JupyterLab and IPython, **if `dropna()` is executed in the same cell as the `shift()` step, then no warning is issued.** So this might be kernel-related. Here's a [pastebin link to the IPython code](https://pastebin.com/707T9NFs).

Comment: Hmmm, hard question. But if using `.copy()` after each filter then it should working well. If not, I agree, sometimes warning, sometimes not.

Comment: @jezrael **_How_** did that work? Grrr! :-) Could you explain or point me to some documentation about that? I've gone through "[Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)" already; but to me, that doesn't explain why `df = df.dropna()` is the cause. Seems like the re-assigned `df` points to an in-memory-only copy of itself which has no other _variable_-based references. Otherwise, I'd have to make `df.dropna(inplace=True)` my default way of using it (which also fixes the issue).

Comment: Hmm, because filtering, so same possible warning with `df.drop_duplicates()` like `df.dropna()` or `df.query('col > 100')` or `df[df['col'] > 100]`

Comment: Ah ok, so it has nothing to do with _chained indexing_ or `__getitem__(...).__setitem__(...)` as described in the docs? Didn't realise _filtering_ operations would cause that problem if re-assigning back to the original `df` or whichever variable. Would that mean, in general, when trimming down a dataframe while filtering, one should always re-assign with `<filter operation>.copy()` ?

Comment: `Would that mean, in general, when trimming down a dataframe while filtering, one should always re-assign with <filter operation>.copy()` Yes, agree. Then this should always prevent this warning.

Comment: if you ignore the astype(int) for a bit , do you still get the warning? I am guessing this might be due to dtypes mismatch. But yes , agree on the `copy()` from prev comments.

Comment: @anky after the first `df = df.dropna()`, if I don't do the `astype` step and directly do `df['A'] = 'bar'`, I still get the SWC warning.

Comment: @jezrael If I do the `df = df.dropna()` step _twice_ before doing `astype`, then I don't get the SWC warning. The 'double dropna filtering' somehow stops the warning; or makes it not a copy of the original.